# PMOS Saturation Condition

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, analog, pmos, analog-switch

we know for nmos works in active region, we must have **Vgs-Vth>0** and **Vds>Vgs-Vth.**

For PMOS can I write like this **| Vgs|-|Vth|>0** , **|Vds|>|Vgs|-|Vth|**.

Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: If **| Vgs|-|Vth|>0** were true that would mean that it does not make a difference if I apply \$V_{GS}\$ = 12 V or \$V_{GS}\$ = -12 V. I hope that you agree that that does make a difference, in one case the PMOS will conduct, in the other case it will not. If you disagree then you need to study the behavior of MOSFETs again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong.

The terms \$V_{\text{gs}} \$ and \$V_{\text{ds}} \$ are polarity sensitive, so you cannot just take the absolute values.

The requirements for a PMOS-transistor to be in saturation mode are
$$V_{\text{gs}} \leq V_{\text{to}} \: \: \text{and} \: \:V_{\text{ds}} \leq V_{\text{gs}}-V_{\text{to}}$$
where \$V_{\text{to}} \$ is the threshold voltage for the transistor (which typically is \$-1\text{V} \$ for a PMOS-transistor).

Comment: '0≥Vds≥Vgs−Vto ' does this mean Vds should be greater than zero

Comment: In summary I can say that for PMOS saturation, Vgs≤Vt and Vds<0.

Comment: @Hari There is no need to summarize. The requirement I have written above must be satisfied in order for the PMOS-transistor to be in saturation.